# Using org-goto across multiple files

Tags: org-mode, buffers, org-refile

Is there a way to use `org-goto` with opened buffer files (and maybe agenda files), just like `org-refile` does through `org-refile-targets`?

I have configured `org-refile` to show the options to choose with the buffer (file) name as a prefix, and the headline levels as a path (with `org-refile-use-outline-path` set to `file`). I want to do the same for `org-goto`. Is this possible?

Comment: `org-goto` goes to a different location in the current buffer (while preserving visibillity), so if you want multiple file capabilities, you will need to build them in a layer above `org-goto`. You ask "Is this possible?" - the answer is "of course it's possible", but since there is nothing built-in (AFAIK), you will need to do all the programming yourself.